# Is there a better way to write this SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, self-join

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     A.currency_code AS currency_code,
     NVL (B.Acct_ID, A.Acct_ID) SECND_Acct_ID,
     NVL (B.Type_currency_code, A.Type_currency_code) SECND_Type_currency_code,
     NVL (B.Seg_Type, A.Seg_Type) SECND_Seg_Type,
     NVL (B.B_Func_Code, A.B_Func_Code) SECND_B_Func_Code,
     A.Acct_ID AS PRIM_Acct_ID,
     A.Type_currency_code AS PRIM_Type_currency_code,
     A.Seg_Type AS PRIM_Seg_Type,
     A.B_Func_Code AS PRIM_B_FuncCode
FROM    (SELECT Acct_ID,
           Type_currency_code,
           Seg_Type,
           B_Func_Code,
           B_ID,
           B_NBR,
           currency_code
      FROM BAU
     WHERE P_A_IND IN ('Y')) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT Acct_ID,
           Type_currency_code,
           Seg_Type,
           B_Func_Code,
           B_ID,
           B_NBR,
           currency_code
      FROM BAU
     WHERE P_A_IND IN ('N')) B
ON     A.B_NBR = B.B_NBR
   AND A.B_ID = B.B_ID
   AND A.currency_code = B.currency_code
```

- Purpose is to identify the distinct primary and secondary ( PRIM_Acct_ID, PRIM_Type_currency_code, PRIM_Seg_Type, PRIM_B_FuncCode) columns on the same table.
- The ones which have p_a_ind ( primary indicator ) as Y is primary, else secondary.
- b_nbr, b_id, and currency_code is the primary key where I did a self-join.

*I would like to know/see if there is a better way of writing this query.*

Comment: on the metalevel, you could use aliases that are a bit more descriptive and some lowercase letters, so it's not shouting quite as much.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is suggesting that there's one or more columns that ought to be included in your `JOIN` condition or `WHERE` clause to make it more 'unique'.  And your column names are _terrible_ - there's no need to abbreviate, given that every RDBMS I'm aware of allows double-digit name lengths.

Comment: There's no reason for the `A` sub-select... though it should result in the same execution plan. You could also use `case when` and aggregate functions to use only one tablescan, though it won't look pretty.

Comment: @X-Zero Thanks for the `WHERE clause to make it more 'unique` suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clarify the query by moving the conditions from subqueries to the `where` or the `on` clause, respectively:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    BAU A
LEFT JOIN
        BAU B
ON      B.P_A_IND IN ('N')
        AND A.B_NBR = B.B_NBR
        AND A.B_ID = B.B_ID
        AND A.currency_code = B.currency_code
WHERE   A.P_A_IND IN ('Y')
```